# Counting in Hive based on two column values

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Say I have the following setup

```
A  |   B  |  C 
1  |   3  |  1
1  |   1  |  2
2  |   12 |  1
2  |   4  |  1
```

I'd like to make a column D that looks like:

```
D
1
1
2
2
```

Ideally I'd like to do this all within the same query so the table returned is comprised of A,B,C and D

Comment: can you elaborate on what basis D's output is getting generated from A, B, C?

Comment: Ya, for sure. So, for A = 1 there are is a count of 1 in column C where C =1, and likewise where C = 2. However, when A = 2; we see that C= 1 twice; thus two entries of count 2 in D

Comment: Maybe a better way to say it is that it counts the A,C tuples. Like there is 1 (1,1) 1 (2,1) 2 (2,2) etc..